# AppSync with CDK Deploy Failed with : `There is no scalar implementation for the named 'AWSTimeStamp' scalar type.`

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-cdk, scalar

*Language*: TypeScript

*Tools*: Appsync and CDK

*Summary*: I am trying to use scalar AWSTimeStamp in my Graphql Schema

*Error message*:

`UPDATE_FAILED        | AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema  Schema Creation Status is FAILED with details: Found 1 problem(s) with the schema: There is no scalar implementation for the named  'AWSTimeStamp' scalar type.`

*Schema files*:

index.graphql

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query
type Mutation

scalar AWSTimeStamp

type Address {
  id: ID
  addressNickName: String
  address1: String
  address2: String
  attnTo: String
  city: String
  state: String
  zipCode: String
  country: String
  createdAt: AWSTimeStamp
  updatedAt: AWSTimeStamp
  isActive: Boolean
}
```

dealership.graphql

```
extend type Mutation {
  createDealership(input: CreateDealershipInput): DealershipPayload
}

input CreateDealershipInput {
  engineId: ID!
  name: String
  slug: String
  address: AddressInput
}

type DealershipPayload {
  id: ID
  engineId: ID
  name: String
  slug: String
  salesAddressId: ID
  salesAddress: Address
}

input AddressInput {
  addressNickName: String
  address1: String
  address2: String
  attnTo: String
  city: String
  state: String
  zipCode: String
  country: String
}
```

Note: These two graphql files get auto merged into a schema.graphql

schema.graphql

```
schema { 
  query: Query 
  mutation: Mutation   
}

type Address {
  id: ID
  addressNickName: String
  address1: String
  address2: String
  attnTo: String
  city: String
  state: String
  zipCode: String
  country: String
  createdAt: AWSTimeStamp
  updatedAt: AWSTimeStamp
  isActive: Boolean
}

input AddressInput {
  addressNickName: String
  address1: String
  address2: String
  attnTo: String
  city: String
  state: String
  zipCode: String
  country: String
}

scalar AWSTimeStamp

input CreateDealershipInput {
  engineId: ID!
  name: String
  slug: String
  address: AddressInput
}

type DealershipPayload {
  id: ID
  engineId: ID
  name: String
  slug: String
  salesAddressId: ID
  salesAddress: Address
}

type Mutation {
  createDealership(input: CreateDealershipInput): DealershipPayload
}
```

When I remove 'scalar AWSTimeStamp' and replace the AWSTimeStamp type with 'String' the deploy is successful. I am not certain if I need to import something to use the AWSTimeStamp scalar. I am looking at this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync.GraphqlType.html but I am not certain where to insert this import if this is in-fact what I need. I am very new to GraphQL and CDK. I look forward to some guidance! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **`AWSTimeStamp`** with an upper-case `S`, but the AppSync scalar type is [**`AWSTimestamp`**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html#awstimestamp) with a lowercase `s`.

Comment: Jameson, thank you that worked. I am embarrassed but so grateful to have everything working.